# Error while debugging windows 10 universal app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am developing a windows 10 universal app. There are no build errors in the app. When I am trying to debug, the following error occurred.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Error : DEP0800 : The required framework "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.Midi.GmDls\10.0.10240.0\.\Appx\Neutral\MidiVoices.appx" failed to install. 
error 0x800B010A: The root certificate and all intermediate certificates of the signature in the app package or bundle must be trusted.
```

Why this error occured and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Known Issues section: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MIDI

Comment: Issue has been resolved. pls check update in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @Hans Passant mentioned, this is a known issue.

It is because the MidiVoice.appx is not properly signed in current version of SDK. This issue has been fixed in TH2 SDK. So you will be able to make it work when TH2 SDK update available to you.

[**Update**]

[Visual Studio update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-update1-vs) included the TH2 SDK update. The issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Mild correction -- the update 1 doesn't seem to have the right version.  You need the "10586" SDK, not the "10240" version.  I downloaded [tools for universal windows app](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619614) and then hand-selected the latest SDK.

After the project had to be hand-edited to bump up the min version (installing the 586 SDK will unintall the 10240 SDK) and reload.  There's a scary "reinstall missing features" that actually doesn't seem to do anything, and the DLS reference needs to be removed and re-added.